# Search table with method query spring boot thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem when I try to add search form to my table. I wont to search in some table column with method query. I use parameter with @RequestParam and process it to method but when I input something to search, it always show me whole table. There are no errors in Spring boot console.

Here are my classes:
**predmeti.html**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${predmet}" th:action="@{/predmeti}" method="get">
            <p class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" th:name="imeZaPretragu" th:value="${search}" class="form-control"/></p>
            <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pretraži"/></p>
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(predmeti)}">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Prezime</th>
```

**PredmetController**

```
private PredmetiRepository predmetiRepository;

@Autowired
public void setPredmetiRepository(PredmetiRepository predmetiRepository) {
    this.predmetiRepository = predmetiRepository;
}
@GetMapping("/predmeti/")
public String pretraziPredmet(@RequestParam(value="search", required = true) String imeZaPretragu, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("predmeti", predmetiRepository.findByPrezime(imeZaPretragu));
    return "predmeti";
}
```

**PredmetRepository**

```
public interface PredmetiRepository extends JpaRepository<Predmet, Long> {

Iterable<Predmet> findByPrezime(String imeZaPretragu);
```

}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `method="post"` instead

Comment: When I use post method and I try to search something, it insert one empty row to table below. Any other suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Does anybody know this?

Comment: What do you want to do actually ? Search item from database and show it ?

Comment: Yes, table is from database. I want to find single row according to search word.